# AngularJS - Load Controller asynchronously From AJAX Without Changing Route

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I want to dynamically load an angular controller upon an ajax call that renders a new view(HTML).

Here is what i have:

example of a view. HTML Snippet From AJAX

```
    <!-- CVS Pharmacy Extracare - Add View -->

<div ng-controller="cvsViewCtrl" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h3 id="asset-title" class=""></h3>
    <br>
    <p>Member ID</p>
    <input class="input-s1 block-elm transition" type="text" placeholder=""/>
    <br>

    <input class="add-asset-btn btn btn-success block-elm transition" type="button" value="Add Asset!" ng-click="prepareCVS();"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

the separate script that pertains to the view

```
App.controller('cvsViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('cvs view loaded');

    $scope.prepareCVS = function() {
      console.log('admit one');
    }
  }]);
```

and the function that loads them

```
$scope.setAddAssetView = function(a) {
      console.log(a);

      if($scope.currentAddView == a) {
        console.log('view already set');
        return;
      }

      $scope.currentAddView = a;

      $('#main-panel').html('');
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/action/setaddassetview',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
          asset: a,
        }
      }).then(function(resp){
        // Success Callback
        // console.log(resp);
        var index = resp.data.view.indexOf('<s');
        var script = resp.data.view.slice(index);
        var html = resp.data.view.replace(script, '');

        $('#main-panel').html( html );
        $('#asset-title').text(a.name);

        var indexTwo = a.view.indexOf('/add');
        var scriptLink = insertString(a.view, indexTwo, '/scripts').replace('.html', '.js').replace('.', '');
        console.log( scriptLink );
        window.asset = a;

        $.getScript(scriptLink, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
          console.log('loaded...');
        })

      },
      function(resp){
        // Error Callback
        console.log(resp);
      });
    }
```

when $.getScript runs, the script gets loaded successfully but it doesn't initialize the controller. i even tried:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = scriptLink;
s.innerHTML = null;
s.id = 'widget';

document.getElementById('switch-script').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('switch-script').appendChild( s );
```

this appends the script with the right link but still doesn't get initialized. How can i work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes in your App, and be sure to load the controller file before the html with ng-controller rendered.

```
var App = angular.module("app", [...]);

App.config(["$controllerProvider", function($controllerProvider) {

    App.register = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register,
    }

}]);

App.register.controller('cvsViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('cvs view loaded');

    $scope.prepareCVS = function() {
      console.log('admit one');
    }
}]);
```

Comment: thanks! will try this. which part goes in the separate controller file? or do they do they both go in the main app file?

Comment: @ryanwaite28 , Actually your App defining and App.config are in your app.js file, and you can put your cvsViewCtrl code in any file!

Comment: it actually didn't work for me(i may not be doing it right) but thanks! i will try again another time. I actually found an alternative to my situation that's working good so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That would actually not be the right way to handle things.

If you use ui-router for routing, you can load the controller in the resolve function. A good service for that is [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).

That can be done as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
]);

angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main.view.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/ctrls/main.ctrl.js');
                }],
            }
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: '/second',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/second.view.html',
            controller: 'secondCtrl',
            resolve: {
                loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/ctrls/controller_TWO.ctrl.js');
                }],
            }
        })

});
```

When you're changing from one route to another, resolve will be triggered before the html is loaded and the controller will be registered properly.